# "id is already registered" error on widget with no id

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

I'm new to dojo and dijit and have been having trouble for about a week now creating widgets that contain other widgets. I've looked at many other articles about this error but haven't had any luck implementing the solutions listed in them.

In short, I'm using dojo 1.10 and I have a templated widget containing a non-templated widget. When I load my page, I get the error *Error: Tried to register widget with id==mtt_SearchPane2_0_searchPane but that id is already registered.*

I haven't given anything an explicit id, and I'm not calling parse anywhere, so I'm kind of stumped.

Here's my html:

```
<body class="claro">
    <div id = "appLayout" ></div>

    <script src="js/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true, parseOnLoad:true"></script>
    <script>
        require([
            "dijit/registry", 
            "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
            "mtt/SearchPane2",
            "dojo/domReady!"],
            function(registry, BorderContainer, SearchPane )
            {
                var appLayout = new BorderContainer({
                    design: "headline"
                }, "appLayout");

                var searchPane = new SearchPane ( { region : "center" } );
                appLayout.addChild ( searchPane );
                searchPane.startup ();

                appLayout.startup();                    

            });
    </script>
</body>
```

I've got a SearchPane widget, like so:

```
define  ( 
[
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixIn",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!mtt/templates/SearchPane2.html",
    "mtt/ImageCheckBox",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], 
function ( declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixIn, _WidgetsInTemplateMixIn, template, ImageCheckBox )
{
    return declare ( 
        "mtt.SearchPane2",
        [ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixIn, _WidgetsInTemplateMixIn ], 
        {
            templateString: template,
        } 
    );
});
```

With an associated template :

```
<div>
    <div
        data-dojo-attach-point="checkBox"
        data-dojo-type="mtt/ImageCheckBox"
    />
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="contentPane"></div>
    moo
</div>
```

And that in turn contains an ImageCheckBox:

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
    "dijit/_WidgetBase"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase )
{

    return declare("mtt/ImageCheckBox", [_WidgetBase ], {
    });
});
```

.. which has no template.

Oddly, if I have ImageCheckBox inherit from _TemplatedMixin instead of _WidgetBase, it's fine.

Thanks in advance to anybody who can shed light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm noticing several issues here. First of all, you're using `require()` inside `ImageCheckBox`. Obviously you need to do the same thing as in your `SearchPane2` widget, you will need to use `define()`.

---

In `SearchPane2` you're using the module `"dijit/_TemplatedMixIn"`, this module does not exist, because the second "i" in "mixin" should be lowercase as well. The correct module name would be`"dijit/_TemplatedMixin"`.

---

But the reason why you get these "widgets already registered" errors, is because you're not overriding the DOM in `ImageCheckBox`. What happens here is quite funny:

- You use `data-dojo-type="mtt/ImageCheckBox"` inside the template of the `SearchPane2`
- The mixin `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` makes sure that the `mtt/ImageCheckBox` module is loaded
- However, your `_mtt/ImageCheckBox` does not change the DOM, so the original DOM node (with the `data-dojo-type="mtt/ImageCheckBox"` on it) will stay
- Then, after your module is loaded, the `parseOnLoad: true` property will render all declaratively instantiated widgets
- Because `data-dojo-type="mtt/ImageCheckBox"` is still on your template, it tries to re-register the widget, which leads to the errors you get.

This obviously won't happen when you inherit from `dijit/_TemplatedMixin` or if you actually implement your widget, because at that time you will probably override the current DOM node, so that the `data-dojo-type` attr disappears.

Or you could do the following in `ImageCheckBox`:

```js
define([
  "dojo/_base/declare", 
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dojo/dom-attr"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, domAttr) {
    return declare("mtt/ImageCheckBox", [_WidgetBase], {

      postCreate: function() {
        domAttr.remove(this.domNode, "data-dojo-type");
      }
    });
});
```

A working example can be found on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yuBn59YvDFTfClrZAU6P?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed response. I've implemented your suggestions and done some basic implementation for the CheckBox widget, and everything looks like it's working now.

Marking this as answered.